# Build of main branch fails

Tags: protobuf-net

When I clone the main branch from github to my PC and build with VS 2019 all is fine. When I than add this to our local git, the build fails with the message about Nerdbank.GitVersioning (The version parameter must be equal or greater than 0). When I rename the .git directory I can compile again, but than I have no source control in place which I need for our own changes. I can't find anything about this and want to ask, if you have any idea how this can be sorted?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that when you say

> When I than add this to our local git

you mean you've taken a disconnected copy of the code in a vanilla repository. If so, what is probably biting you is some minor version number tweaking in `src/version.json`, specifically:

```json
"versionHeightOffset": -18,
```

Note that the entire *point* of `Nerdbank.GitVersioning` is to infer versioning from the git state, so if you are now in a different repository `Nerdbank.GitVersioning` will give you an entirely different version output. This gives a few options:

1. disable `Nerdbank.GitVersioning`
2. fight the fight with `src/version.json`
3. leave the code in a regular clone of the original repository (not a detached file copy)
4. just consume [the NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/) and stop worrying about the build completely